# gloud-java. PERMISSION_DENIED: Google Cloud Pub/Sub API (Experimental)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I use gloud-java experimental library. After update today, error occurred.
Run example from library local (This error is automatically appeared in the google cloud flexible engine, although deploy not produced for a week)

```
public class PullTest {
private static final transient Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getName());

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    try (PubSub pubsub = PubSubOptions.defaultInstance().service()) {
        String subscriptionName = "subscription-segment";
        Subscription subscription = pubsub.getSubscription(subscriptionName);
    }
}
}
```

throw exception

```
Aug 10, 2016 2:19:08 AM io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl <init>
INFO: [ManagedChannelImpl@131ef10] Created with target pubsub-experimental.googleapis.com:443
Aug 10, 2016 2:19:08 AM io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl <init>
INFO: [ManagedChannelImpl@394df057] Created with target pubsub-experimental.googleapis.com:443
Aug 10, 2016 2:19:10 AM io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl maybeTerminateChannel
INFO: [ManagedChannelImpl@131ef10] Terminated
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.pubsub.PubSubException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Google Cloud Pub/Sub API (Experimental) has not been used in project google.com:cloudsdktool before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/pubsub-experimental.googleapis.com/overview?project=google.com:cloudsdktool then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
at com.google.cloud.pubsub.spi.DefaultPubSubRpc$1.apply(DefaultPubSubRpc.java:183)
at com.google.cloud.pubsub.spi.DefaultPubSubRpc$1.apply(DefaultPubSubRpc.java:177)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CatchingFuture.doFallback(Futures.java:842)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CatchingFuture.doFallback(Futures.java:834)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$AbstractCatchingFuture.run(Futures.java:789)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:456)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:817)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:753)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:634)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.setException(SettableFuture.java:53)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.RetryingCallable$Retryer$1.onFailure(RetryingCallable.java:139)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1764)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:456)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:817)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:753)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:634)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.setException(SettableFuture.java:53)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionTransformingCallable$1.onFailure(ExceptionTransformingCallable.java:90)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1764)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:456)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:817)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:753)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:634)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:331)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:307)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$3.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:462)
at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:54)
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:154)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.grpc.ApiException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Google Cloud Pub/Sub API (Experimental) has not been used in project google.com:cloudsdktool before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/pubsub-experimental.googleapis.com/overview?project=google.com:cloudsdktool then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
... 18 more
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Google Cloud Pub/Sub API (Experimental) has not been used in project google.com:cloudsdktool before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/pubsub-experimental.googleapis.com/overview?project=google.com:cloudsdktool then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:503)
... 11 more
Aug 10, 2016 2:19:10 AM io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl maybeTerminateChannel
INFO: [ManagedChannelImpl@394df057] Terminated
```

How to get around this problem? 
The problem arose out of nothing. In the morning it worked :)

p.s.

$ gcloud info

shows the correct information

$ gcloud auth login

did not help

Answer (score 1):

(Caveat: I work on the team building the equivalent library for .NET. That means I know a certain amount of the infrastructure involved, but I don't know any Java-specific details.)

If you're just trying to use the PubSub v1 API, I believe the problem is that it's connecting to `pubsub-experimental.googleapis.com` instead of `pubsub.googleapis.com`. I'm not sure why it's treating that as the default endpoint - the [default host in the code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/blob/master/gcloud-java-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/PubSubOptions.java#L34) look okay - but I believe you should be able to fix it by setting the host manually:

```
PubSubOptions options = PubSubOptions.builder().host("pubsub.googleapis.com").build();
try (PubSub pubsub = options.service()) {
    String subscriptionName = "subscription-segment";
    Subscription subscription = pubsub.getSubscription(subscriptionName);
}
```

Given that the source code in github seems okay, you might also want to check that you're using the latest published version of the library... it may well be that the default host has been fixed in that. As per comments, gcloud-java 0.2.7 uses the correct host by default.

Comment: I am puzzled that the code does not work in the cloud. He has not changed a week.
I checked your code - the same result. I'll try to debug.
may be google change experimental version pub/sub engine

Comment: @vadbabushkin: While your code hasn't changed, I wouldn't be surprised if the `pubsub-experimental` endpoint had been disabled for public projects, for example. Note that I get the same error as you for `pubsub-experimental`, but not for `pubsub`. You should also double check that the project really *does* have pubsub enabled.

Comment: @JonSkeet is right, pubsub-experimental is no longer available. gcloud-java 0.2.7 is out and fixes this issue by using pubsub.googleapis.com by default. Jon, do you want to add this to your answer?

Comment: @mziccard: Thanks, have added that in.